Vue3 fragment that allows v-for without any wrapper element
In Vue2 there was this fragment library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fragment?activeTab=readme
In Vue3 they added built-in fragment: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/new/fragments
But how do I create a v-for with this built-in fragment without getting this error:
ESLint: The template root disallows 'v-for' directives.(vue/no-multiple-template-root)

It seems to me that the new built-in functionality is not as good as the old library.
This was working fine in Vue2, but it seems impossible to do in Vue3:
<fragment>
    <template v-for="id in ids" :key="id">
        <div class="1"></div>
        <div class="2"></div>
    </template>
</fragment>


This is not a real error but linter error, whether a user gets depends on how ESLint is configured. If you don't want to receive the error, disable the rule.
This is Vue 2 ESLint rule and it's not applicable to Vue 3:

This rule checks whether template contains single root element valid for Vue 2.

It's possible there is no functional parity between vue-fragment and Vue 3 fragments but this is not the case here, v-for is allowed on template root:


Vue.createApp()
.component('test', {
  template: `
    <template v-for="id in ids" :key="id">
      <div class="1">{{id}}</div>
      <div class="2">{{id}}</div> 
    </template>
  `,
  setup() {
    return {ids: [1,2]};
  }
})
.mount("#app");
<div id="app">
    <test></test>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.21/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>




When you say there is "not a real error", do you mean that it will actually run, cuz I doubt that?

Regarding the answer itself, it's not what I asked. Vue-fragment lib is meant to be used for wrapping a component html, not to write it directly in app. My question is is about components without wrapper element.

Yes, I mean this. The error exists because you mistakenly configured the linter to cause it. It looks you stopped at linter error and didn't check how this actually works with Vue 3 compiler. 

@Morco since Vue3, you can totally have several nodes at the apex without a need for a wrapper is what Estus explained here. Fragments do not have a lot of reason to exist in Vue3 anymore: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/new/fragments

I ended up using custom JS after mounting, and it seems to be working, but it's annoying that Vue3 doesn't provide this functionality directly.
const fragmentRef = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
    const fragment = fragmentRef.value
    if (!fragment) return

    const parent = fragment.parentElement
    if (!parent) return

    while (fragment.firstChild) {
        parent.insertBefore(fragment.firstChild, fragment)
    }

    parent.removeChild(fragment)
})


Please don't modify the DOM like that.

Why not, please provide more details.

VueJS is in charge of the shadow DOM regarding any changes happening. But unlike jQuery, it uses State for that. Both are quite different approaches. If you want to use VueJS, prefer not to mess up with the DOM itself too much and follow the patterns of the framework. Otherwise, you can always use petitve-vue or Alpine.

@kissu It's possible to do this when necessary, this is what vue-fragment did in the first place. But this is also a reason why it had a bunch of unresolved issues

@EstusFlask I agree that it could be used as a last resort but should not be the go-to way. Here it also looks quite unnecessary after a mount to the DOM and given the native solution that we have. I'm also seeing some people using Vue alongside jQuery, hence why I warm about mixing the two together. Good to know that this is what vue-fragment did back in the time tho.
